# Is it OK to use javascript to set the initial style

Tags: javascript, css

Please test this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GATA/NXa7k/1/).

The whole layout bounce back and forth at the beginning. It seems that it is waiting for Javascripts code interpretation.

I use this code to set the width.

```
document.getElementById("headc").setAttribute("style","width:800px;");
```

Comment: why do you do it like that?

Comment: i think that initial state must be declaired in code ( inline or in css file, but in html )

Comment: @NicoO It is just a test for now, I am trying to get the screen width then add 90% of it(in pixels) to the header as a reference value.

Comment: well yes, the style won't be set until the page gets to the point of running that code. So you may indeed see a "bounce" or "flicker" of some kind, depending on numerous things, e.g. where your element actually is on the page vs. that js code, how long the page is taking to load, etc.. now, whether or not this is "okay" is a matter of opinion

Comment: @CrayonViolent Thank you :) I want to use php to set a range of initial CSS atributes. Is it ok?

Comment: well, php can't directly set css attributes, since it is executed server-side. It can however output stuff like javascript to be executed or css rules to be evaluated.  And on that note.. if you are using php to output this stuff, why not output css rules in the head to begin with?

Comment: What would be the difference between your JS code, and using `#ttt{width:800px;}` in the first place in your opinion …?

Comment: @CrayonViolent That was my first idea to use PHP but I thought it might be wrong to do it these days. I left web designing 8 years ago now I am struggling to remember those things and use them again :)

Comment: @CBroe Hi I am trying to design a dynamic layout, That's why I am trying to use java script or php to generate a width based on users screen width.

Comment: Oh, that makes it even worse than your question initially sounded :-) Look into what is called _responsive_ layout and _CSS media queries_.

Comment: @CBroe I know about it :) but With MQ's you are defining a range of values to capture the screen width , I want the precise width.

Comment: _“I want the precise width”_ – why, what for? What if the user loaded your page in a small window, and then changes its size? What if they are using a smartphone/tablet, and change the orientation from layout to portrait mode or vice versa? All this is handled by media queries quite well – whereas a “PHP solution” would be unable to react on that at all (on itself), and with JS you would be re-implementing stuff that media queries already have “built in” … makes little sense to me.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you I hadn't thought about it like that :) But I think We can also generate the expected media query for that too. I think I need to learn more about media queries:) Thank you again.

Comment: Sounds like you want an Adaptive Web Design (code for predefined layouts) but use some Responsive Web Design (fluid layout) methods to decide what to set things to. This isn't necessarily a bad thing, but one of the major selling points of AWD is that most if not all logic is done server-side.  So if you're going to dive into client-side methods to detect and build stuff.. (IMO) you may as well just go with RWD at that point. Here is an article that you may find useful: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/what-is-the-difference-between-responsive-vs-adaptive-web-design/

Comment: @CrayonViolent I think I want the best of both worlds:) Thank you again for your instructive comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some instances where you want to set it with javascript like this but only when you need some initial effect like divs arriving at the center and so on. If you only need static initial declaration then you should use inline definition or css. For one, there is certain delay between loading DOM structure and firing javascript (in case you are firing js after the DOM is loaded which you should in this case). For fwo, you are forcing some additional computational power to be used where it is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Don't set the initial width using Javascript. Do it directly in the HTML or CSS.